# Using dependant types to provide a compile type proofe that some integer is a valid row-id in database?

Tags: database, dependent-type

In my never-ending wonder in dependent type land a strange idea came into my head. I do a lot of data base programming and it would be nice if I could get rid of all those sanity-checking and validity-checking. One specially annoying case is those functions that accept an Integer and expect that to be a valid row-id of some certain table. A very silly example is:

```
function loadStudent(studentId: Integer) : Student
```

Supposing my language of choice supports dependent types in their full glory, would it be possible to utilize the type system to make `loadStudent` accept only valid `studentId` values :

```
function loadStudent(studentId : ValidRowId("students_table") ) : Student
```

If yes, how do I write a data constructor for `ValidRowId` type? All the examples I have seen thus far were pure (no IO involved).

Comment: This is an interesting question, and one I've thought a fair amount about, without coming up with a decent answer. The problem is, the outside world changes, so you could encode a timestamp in the "effectful proof of database presence" but that doesn't really capture what we really want. The problem is fundamentally that I could get a proof that the row id is valid one instant and someone could delete the row the next. I have a feeling that the real answer is to make everything persistent all the way down :)

Comment: The problem also encodes some of the conventional (concurrency) wisdom about "don't test then do", since if I had a predicate about a file existing and an effectful decision procedure, there's nothing that proof tells me other than that the file existed at a particular instant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I don't see how it's possible without doing IO. How can you know that an id is valid without searching the database to see if there is a record with that id?

I suppose that you could, at program start up time, read all the current IDs into a table in memory and then do your checks against that. But you would have to somehow know if another user had added or deleted records after you created the table.

Okay, you could have all threads on all computers that access the database communicate with some central server that keeps this master list so that it would always be current. But we already have a central place that keeps track of all the IDs currently in use in the database: it's called "the database". What would be the advantage of going to a whole bunch of work to maintain a duplicate copy of a subset of the data on the database? It's unlikely you'd get much performance gain, and you'd create the possibility that bugs in your code, bad connections, etc, would result in the data getting out of sync.